# Referencing composer version on branched **and** tagged repository

Tags: git, branch, composer-php, git-tag

I have got some private development repositories used to host some of my personal composer packages. I create branches for all major versions (versions 0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9, ..., 1.0, 1.1, ..., 2.0, etc.) and inside that branches I tag certain commits with minor versions (0.1.1, 0.1.2, ..., 0.1.x, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, ..., 0.2.x).

1) Assuming I have a branch 0.1 including a **tagged** commit 0.1.0. When I require the version ~0.1 (which should match all versions >=0.1,<1.0), does composer fetch the commit tagged 0.1.0 or the latest commit inside that branch?

2) Assuming I have a branch 0.1 with **no** tagged commits in there. When I require the version ~0.1 (which again should match all versions >=0.1,<1.0), does composer take the **latest** commit inside the branch '0.1'?

I have already read the whole composer documentation and found [this article](http://qpleple.com/understand-composer-versions/) which indeed is helpful but something is still missing in my head to understand how the hell composer actually resolves versions to a specific commit when I use both branches and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made some tests with the exact scenario like described in my question and this is the result:

1) Composer fetches the last tagged commit

2) Composer fails to resolve the dependency with the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
  - The requested package tworabbits/composer-test could not be found in any version, 
    there may be a typo in the package name.
```